# How to quickly refresh several workdirs related to one git-repo

Tags: git, opengrok

I have a project, that is stored as a git-repo. The repo has several branches. Also I use OpenGrok (source browser) for the project. To be able to show all branches I cloned the project several times, after that did 'checkout' the required branch.

To update each workdir I do 'git fetch && git merge' for each workdir.

The Q: Is there a way to have one "main" clone, where need to do git fetch. After that each workdir will be updated from the "main" clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly that Problem ist addressed by the `git worktree` commands: one repo but several working trees. Lookup the manual for that command!

Answer (score 0):

The question does not state the reason for avoiding `git fetch` in the branch clones so I will take it as 2 part question.

If the reason is say to save network bandwidth, you can change the `origin` of the branch clones to the main Git repository.

Alternatively, if the question is to find means to efficiently synchronize the branch clones, I'd recommend to take a look at the Python tools supplied with OpenGrok. Specifically, the `opengrok-mirror` tool provides a way to "synchronize" local repositories with their origins. See https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/Repository-synchronization for details.